# Spelling of monotonous

Tags: historical-linguistics, linguistic-typology, cross-linguistic, comparative-linguistics

All, I am just curious why 'monotonous' is spelled as mo·​not·​o·​nous and not as
mono.tonus following the Greek origin of the word as mono + tone. Mono and tone could be spelled alone and actually they constitute the word monotonous. Thanks

Comment: English hyphenation is a complex matter. It’s presumably so you know that the second and fourth o’s are pronounced /ɒ/ and /ə, /not /əʊ/.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet. Somehow I do not think the question is about hyphenation.

Comment: @fdb I didn’t even notice the difference between _-ous_ and _-us_ before – I don’t see what the interpuncts would indicate if not that this is about hyphenation…

Comment: Are you asking why the word is pronounced with stress on the second syllable rather than the first and third?

Comment: I think you might be confusing spelling and pronunciation. If you're asking about why it ends in -ous and not -us, @fdb has a good answer. You might be asking why we spell it with one word instead of two, or why it's stressed in a particular way. I'm not qualified to answer either of those questions, so if that _is_ your question, I'd suggest you ask a new one.

Comment: @VincentBechmann thanks for the clarification, actually, I meant the pronunciation. I going to ask a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are asking why this word is spelt with -ous rather than with -us. In English, -ous is the usual offshoot of Latin -ōsus in words borrowed via Old French; the development is -ōsus > -eux > -ous. Later, this spelling is adopted also for words taken directly from Latin or Greek. We have *glorious, copious, generous* and lots more.

Comment: thanks, what about the other way around, I mean spelling mono instead of mo.not..

Comment: @Kernel The stressed vowel in *monotonous* (the so-called "short O") is a checked vowel, i.e. one that is never found without a consonant after it, unlike the third vowel in *monotone*. As for why it's pronounced that way, look up [trisyllabic laxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trisyllabic_laxing).

Comment: Latin *-us* developed to Old French *-s* usually; Latin unstressed u in a final syllable was lost. So Old French had *-s* as a masculine nominative singular ending. In modern French, Old French's nominative forms in *-s* have mostly been lost (with a few exceptions like *fils* < *filius*); modern French noun forms are mostly derived from the Old French oblique forms based on Latin accusatives, with endings like *-um.* French *-eux* is instead from Latin *-osus/-osum*; that is why the feminine version of the ending is *-euse* (from *-osa*).

Comment: @brasstacks. I am talking about loan words, of course, not inherited words.

Comment: French doesn't loan Latin *-us* as *-eux* either; it loans it as *-us,* or sometimes adapts it to *-e.* Latin *monotonus* corresponds to French *[monotone](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/monotone)*; I don't think *monotoneux* is even a commonly used form in French. There are words that had *-ous* added as a suffix in English despite generally not having *-eux* in French or *-osus* in Latin. But this is at least in part a morphological adaptation; it's not just a phonetic/orthographic alteration of Latin *-us.*

Comment: https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/133383#eid33090464

Comment: Yes; that entry says that the English *-ous* suffix, French *-eux* suffix, and Old French *-us, -os*, etc. suffix cannot be viewed as just an adaptation of Latin *-us*: "**Latin adjectives in -ōsus [...] had in Old French forms in -os , or -us (-ous )**, e.g. coveitos , coveitus[...]". "it is evident however that igneous , for example, answers not only to Latin igneus , but to ignea , igneum , etc., and that **the -ous is an additional element**. And in comparing alacrious with alacer , hilarious with hilaris , capacious with capax , capāci-, the suffixal nature of the -ous is manifest."